# Query UI, inheriting a widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, widget, client-side-scripting

I'm trying to build a custom widget called Staticblock. I want to use the Resizable widget as the prototype. I thought a widget could be inherited and if no changes were made to the sub widget (no methods add or overridden) it would behave like the inherited widget(Resizable).

```
$.widget( "my.staticblock", $.ui.resizable, {
    /*
      methods go here
    */
});
```

Now, shouldn't I be able to use "staticblock" as if it were "resizable". Like so...

```
$( "#resizable1").staticblock();
```

Ok, that works but if I pass an option I get an error. Like so..

```
$( "#resizable1").staticblock({
    containment: "parent"
});
```

containment: "parent" is a valid option for the Resizable widget. The below works
fine..

```
$( "#resizable1").resizable({
    containment: "parent"
});
```

The error I get is related to this chunk of code in the jQuery UI.

```
 $.ui.plugin.add("resizable", "containment", {

start: function() {
    var element, p, co, ch, cw, width, height,
        that = $(this).data("ui-resizable"),
        o = that.options,
        el = that.element,
        oc = o.containment,
        ce = (oc instanceof $) ? oc.get(0) : (/parent/.test(oc)) ?    
                    el.parent().get(0) : oc;

    if (!ce) {
        return;
    } ...
```

In my humble attempt to figure it out I was able to determine that when using the
staticblock widget "that" is undefined on execution of the line

```
that = $(this).data("ui-resizable").
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: I should have said "that" is undefined after execution of the line.

Comment: Any help is great, even a point in the right direction. I don't mind doing my homework. Please :(

Comment: I know the reason why this is happening. Is because its now using my custom widget my-staticblock as the key storage name for .data cache. not ui-resizable. In the widget bridge if I change $.data( this, fullName, new object( options, this ) ); to $.data( this, "ui-resizable", new object( options, this ) ); it works as expected. How can this be done without messing with the jQuery core code.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that nobody has ever had this issue when trying to inherit from a widget. **If you inherit from the ui.resizable widget and use one of the acceptable options for the "resizable" widget the code won't render**. Please let me know what you think.